Can't figure out why my user object isn't being created when SignUp form is submitted in my spring App.ERROR: relation "users_seq" does not exist
Sun Jun 23 19:58:26 EDT 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not extract ResultSet [ERROR: relation "users_seq" does not exist Position: 16] [select nextval('users_seq')]; SQL [select nextval('users_seq')]
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet [ERROR: relation "users_seq" does not exist
  Position: 16] [select nextval('users_seq')]; SQL [select nextval('users_seq')]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:277)

Here is a sample of the thymeleaf form where I am passing data from:
First Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}"  />
        <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}"
              th:errors="*{firstName}"
              class="error"></span>
        <br><br>

        Username:  <input type="text" th:field="*{userName}"  />
        <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('userName')}"
              th:errors="*{userName}"
              class="error"></span>
        <br><br>

        Email:     <input type="text" th:field="*{email}"  />
        <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}"
              th:errors="*{email}"
              class="error"></span>
        <br><br>

Here is the Controller methods that are using the form data:
 @RequestMapping("/signup")
    public String signup(Model theModel) {

        User theUser = new User();
        theModel.addAttribute("user", theUser);

        return "signup";
    }

    @PostMapping("/confirmation")
    public String confirmation(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User theUser,
            BindingResult bindingResult) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "signup";
        } else {

            userService.save(theUser);

            return "confirmation";
        }
    }

First time using Spring boot. Definitely dumbfounded. Not sure where I need to change the model. From my understanding using ModelAttribute should automagically get all the fields when the form is submitted right?
My Postgresql db is already created with all the necessary columns. It's connected too.
This is User class with the table setup as well:
 @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull(message="Name is required")
    @Size(min=2, message="is required")
    private String firstName;

    @Size(message = "Username should be at least 5 characters")
    @NotNull(message="Username is required")
    private String userName;

    @NotNull(message="Please enter a valid email address.")
    @Email(message = "Not a valid email", regexp = "[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,3}",
            flags = Pattern.Flag.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
    private String email;

    @Min(16)
    @NotNull(message = "Please enter an age above 16.")
    private int age;

    @Min(24)
    @NotNull(message = "Please enter a height above 24 inches.")
    private int height;

    @NotNull(message = "You must select a gender for calorie assignment")
    private String gender;

    @NotNull(message = "Are you so lazy, you don't even wanna pick activity level?")
    private String activityLevel;

    @Min(85)
    @NotNull(message = "You need to enter a weight above 85 pounds.")
    private int weight;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "friends_list",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "friend_id")
    )
    private Set<User> friendsList = new HashSet<>();

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof User)) {
            return false;
        }
        User other = (User) o;
        return id != null && id.equals(other.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }

    public User() {

    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }


    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }


    public void setActivityLevel(@NotNull(message = "Are you so lazy, you don't even wanna pick activity level?") String activityLevel) {
        this.activityLevel = activityLevel;
    }

    public String getActivityLevel() {
        return activityLevel;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

DDL :
create table users
(
    id            integer not null
        primary key,
    firstname     varchar(255),
    username      varchar(255),
    email         varchar(255),
    age           integer,
    height        integer,
    weight        integer,
    gender        varchar(255),
    activitylevel varchar(255)
);

alter table users
    owner to #####;

changed @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) to @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) and getting
2024-06-23T23:25:58.062-04:00 ERROR 5611 --- [fitBuddyApp] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement [ERROR: column "activity_level" of relation "users" does not exist
  Position: 20] [insert into users (activity_level,age,email,first_name,gender,height,user_name,weight) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) 


Looks like your users table is configured to use a Sequence to determine the next Id value to use (users_seq) but that Sequence is not created.   Provide more information on your database setup and the full code to the User class

@AndrewL updated more info from user class. And added DDL as well.

just realized I should be using @Generated Value(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) probably shouldn't I?

Okay I figured it out. When I created the Table on the terminal,
I didn't add the id as serial.
So I ended up creating a sequence, inserting into the table and then added this tidbit in the users code.
 @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_gen",
            sequenceName = "users_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Integer id;

Fixed the issue. Postgres I guess the seq needs to match the table name.
